# Variable with Wildcards

Tags: powershell

This code seems to return all the DHCP leases and not the specific computer I'm looking for. If I remove the **Read-Host** line and instead insert the search string manually like this: `Where-Object {$_.HostName -like "*sdub*"` then I'll get a match with a computer.

```
$HOSTNAME = Read-Host 'Input part of the computer name'
$HOSTLIST = Invoke-Command -ComputerName services02 -ArgumentList $HOSTNAME -Scriptblock {
    Get-DHCPServerv4scope | Get-DHCPServerv4Lease | Where-Object {
        $_.HostName -like "*$($Args[0])*" 
    }
}
foreach($HOSTINLIST in $HOSTLIST) {
    $HOSTINLIST | Format-Table -Property HostName, IPAddress, 
        @{Label="Online"; Expression={Test-Connection $HOSTINLIST.IPAddress -Count 1 -Quiet}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by **$using:HostName** instead of passing the variable via `-ArgumentList`:

```
$HostName = Read-Host 'Input part of the computer name'
$HostList = Invoke-Command -ComputerName services02 -Scriptblock { Get-DHCPServerv4scope | Get-DHCPServerv4Lease | Where-Object {$_.HostName -like "*$using:HostName*" } }
foreach($HostInList in $HostList) {
$HostInList | Format-Table -Property HostName, IPAddress, @{Label="Online"; Expression={Test-Connection $HostInList.IPAddress -Count 1 -Quiet}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54975799/45375), the **PSv3+ use of the special `$using:` scope** - which allows incorporating variable values from the *caller*'s scope into script blocks executed *remotely* - **solves your problem**. See the bottom section if you need to solve the problem in PowerShell v2.

---

As for **why your original approach based on `-ArgumentList` didn't work**:

While the script block passed to `Invoke-Command` *does* see whatever was passed via `-ArgumentList` in its *immediate* scope, **any commands in it that run *via a script block (`{ ... }`)*** - even if they technically run in the *same* scope, as is the case with `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object` - **do *not* see the same `$Args` array, unless it is *explicitly relayed*** - which is *not* an option with script blocks passed to cmdlets such as `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object`.

A simplified example (that doesn't even use remoting, which is incidental to the original problem):

```
Invoke-Command { 

  # OK - sees 'foo', because $Args reflects what was passed via -ArgumentList
  "0: $($Args[0])"

  # !! Does NOT see foo', because the script block executed by ForEach-Object
  # !! - even though it runs in the same scope - has its own $Args definition
  # !! and given that NO arguments were passed to *it*, the $Args that it
  # !! sees is *empty* (an empty array).
  'bar' | ForEach-Object { "1: $($Args[0])" } 

} -ArgumentList 'foo'
```

The above yields:

```
0: foo
1:
```

which shows that the script block passed to `ForEach-Object` no longer sees the same `$Args` value as the top-level scope of the script block passed to `Invoke-Command`.

---

You could **make your original approach work** as follows (which is necessary if you're stuck with PowerShell v2):

```
Invoke-Command { 

  # OK - sees 'foo', because $Args reflects what was passed via -ArgumentList
  "0: $($Args[0])"

  # Save the original $Args array...
  $ArgsSaved = $Args

  # ... and reference the *saved* array in the script block.
  'bar' | ForEach-Object { "1: $($ArgsSaved[0])" } 

} -ArgumentList 'foo'
```